# Particular solution of $a_n - 3a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} = 2n - 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let

$$a_n - 3a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} = 2n - 1$$
$$a_0 = a_1 = 0$$

Be a recurrence relation. To solve it, we need to find homogenous and particular solution. I found out that the homogenous solution is $b_1 + b_2 \cdot 2^n$ for some constants $b_1, b_2$.
To find the particular solution, I say that $a_n ^p = cn + d$ for some constants $c, d$. But when we put it into the recurrence, we get that

$$cn+d - 3(cn - c + d) + 2(cn - 2c + d) = 2n-1$$
$$ (c-3c+2c)n + (d+3c-3d-4c+2d) = 2n-1 $$
$$ -c = 2n-1 $$

and therefore we cant find $d$, so probably guessing that $a_n ^p = cn + d$ is wrong. How do i find the particular solution then? Because I thought that the particular solution is $cn+d$ when $d(n) = \alpha n + \beta$ ( where $d(n)$ is the non homogenous part of the recurrence )...  Thanks to everyone helping!

Comment: Because 1 is a root of the characteristic equation, you will need to and use a quadratic (one degree higher) instead of a linear term.

Comment: If you sum together the first $n$ terms of the relation, you end up with $$a_n-2a_{n-1}=n^2-1$$ Perhaps this will be easier to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\alpha(x):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

We have
$$
(1-3x+2x^2) \alpha(x)= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(a_n-3a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2} \right) x^n=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (2n-1) x^n=\frac{(3-x)x^2}{(x-1)^2}
$$
(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%282n-1%29x%5En%2F%2F%5D+from+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A2%2F%2F%5D+to+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ainfinity%2F%2F%5D) ).
So
$$
\alpha(x)=\frac{(3-x)x^2}{(x-1)^2(1-3x+2x^2)}
$$

Its Taylor series is given by
$$
\alpha(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-n(n+4)+5 (2^n-1) \right) x^n
$$
(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28%283-x%29x%5E2%29%2F%28%28x-1%29%5E2%281-3x%2B2x%5E2%29%29%2F%2F%5D%2C+%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ax%2F%2F%5D%2C+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D%2C+%5B%2F%2Fmath%3An%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D)) and so we have
$$
a_n=\left(-n(n+4)+5 (2^n-1) \right)
$$